# ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and data immutability issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

*.html*

```
 <ion-col size="2" tappable (click)="selectCountry(countryCode)">
      <ion-label>{{countryCode}}</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
```

*.ts*

```
countryCode: string;

  setCountryCode(countryCode: string): void {
    this.countryCode = countryCode;
  }
```

I have enabled `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` everywhere. Now my problem is even though `this.countryCode` has been changed UI never updated. I hope this is due to the data immutability issue. Could you tell me how to handle this kind of use case with `OnPush`?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` you are turning off automatic change detection and you are required to do it manualy here is example how you can do it:

```js
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

setCountryCode(countryCode: string): void {
  this.countryCode = countryCode;
  this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
}
```

Comment: Can't I have another way than this? For me, it is a kind of hack. I would like to have more natural way to do this.

Comment: when you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` it basicly requires from you to call change detection by hand at some point which you may choose in what you showed this is good place to put it but you may move it to some other place that would trigger it

Comment: I would like to have better alternative than this. Do you have any idea about it? Because this kind of thing will add lot of unnecessary code to the code base over time. I would like to do this in a more natural way.

Comment: alternative is remove `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Comment: Another alternative is to use the `@Input()` decorator on your class variables where it makes sense. You know, use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` the way it is supposed to be used. No shortage of resources on the subject all over the internet.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.